# Selecting a random sentence less than 280 characters from a text file

Tags: python, file, random, nltk

I am working on a project where I want to read a large text file,
randomly select a full sentence from that file. 
If that file sentence is less 280 characters or less, print that file out. 
if not select another sentence until it finds a sentence that is less than 280 characters. 
Using nltk I am able to break down the text into individual sentences, select one randomly and count the characters.

```
import nltk.data
import random

tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

fp = open("test.txt")

data = fp.read()

tok = tokenizer.tokenize(data); #breaks into sentences 

newTok = random.choice(tok) #selects random sentence 

length = len(newTok) #gives amount of characters in random sentence
```

I am now trying to work create a `while` loop that will test if a sentence is less than 280 chcaracters to print it, and if it is not will select another sentence randomly to test

```
while length < 280:  # while length of sentence is less than 280

      print "length of sentence = ", length # do this 
      print newTok # do this 
      break #stops loop

      else: 
          print length, " is too long"
```

but this is giving me an invalid syntax error on else, but also I think will not iterate again to find another sentence.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: have you tried using just '\n' or' '\n\n' ?

Comment: You already have a list of sentences via `tokenizer.tokenize(data)`; why don't you use that list directly? `tok = tokenizer.tokenize(data); random.choice(tok)`

Comment: much appreciated @PeterO. I have updated OP with your suggestion and kept other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the list of tokens:

```
tok = tokenizer.tokenize(data); #breaks into sentences
```

...the rest is a one-liner:

```
newTok = random.choice([x for x in tok if len(x)<280])
```

Note the use of a list comprehension with an `if` to narrow the items from the token list to those whose length is less than 280 characters.